# How do I add a subdomain entry for my instance in the Amazon Web Services?

Tags: subdomain, amazon-web-services, cname-record

I have an instance running and I need to point the "elastic ip" to my domain name (www.mydomain.com), I also want to add rsc.mydomain.com, 1.mydomain.com, 2.mydomain.com

How can I do that? Is it in the Amazon Web Services console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably needs to be done at your DNS provider (which may also be your domain registrar), unless you're using Amazon Route53 for DNS. All you need from AWS is the Elastic IP of your instance. To make things easier in the future, you should create your records like this:

```
mydomain.com, A record pointing to your Elastic IP
www.mydomain.com, CNAME pointing to mydomain.com.
rsc.mydomain.com, CNAME pointing to mydomain.com.
1.mydomain.com, CNAME pointing to mydomain.com.
2.mydomain.com, CNAME pointing to mydomain.com.
```